# Dynamic forms with foreign keys in Django 1.7 and Python 3.4

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.4

I know there are A LOT of answers to questions like these, but since Django 1.7 with Python 3.4 is relatively new, it's hard to tell if the other questions are still supported.

I need to know how to implement a scenario where I have a basic template with data fields where I can dynamically add more of a specific field.

So, say a questionnaire with:
Section 1: basic information at the top (required)
Section 2: including 0-10 input on info (optional)
section 3: more basic information that needs to be input (required)
section 4: something similar to section 2 (optional)

I think I have models.py and forms.py figured out. I just implemented it as I would with any other form or model. However, views.py and the javascript in the html is what I am struggling with.

If the implementation is the exact same as earlier Django versions and python then could someone just post a link to that answered question?